# How to handle arrays and borders in Java

Tags: java, arrays, int

If I have an array of integers such as below with `height` and `width`.

```
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

If I have a kernel `1x5 kernel [2 2 3 4 5]` and I want to multiply the kernel with the value of integers. How can I ensure that the kernel is applied to the whole array EXCEPT the first and last column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You can use boundary checks on your own. Could you show your attempt?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Hi yes, I came across `for(int filterX = -filterWidth/2; filterX < filterWidth/2; filterX++)
            for(int filterY = -filterHeight/2; 
                 filterY < filterHeight/2; filterY++)` for similar solution but it takes in account all sides not first and last column

Comment: You want us to read that inline in a comment?  You are calling something a "kernel" and then wanting to use fractional components?  Your question equates to the multiplication (adjusted albeit) of a vector by a matrix and your dimensions don't match.  Whether a programmer or mathematician, I think the question is the same: "What the hell?"

Answer (score 1):

Start from `x-index=1` so first element is at `"2"` and end at `x-index=7` so the last element of kernel will be at `"9"`. Then columns `"1"` and `"10"` will not be touched.

Comment: What if the kernel was 1x5?

Comment: Can you add code and comment it please because its quite confusing

Comment: Of course you should make the code more "synamic" so it can handle other kernel sizes and dimensions. If it  was 1x5 then it should end 2 elments sooner than before.

Comment: Kind of like your question?  What if it's a `m x n` vector?  And then a filter is applied that has a height and width and you need to use 1/2 of those dimensions?

Comment: Jeremy, the vector is `m xn` and I want to multiply that vector the the integer array but dont want the first and last column of the array to be changed as shown in my question